# Postfix not receiving non-local mail

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix, dovecot

I set up a server with Postfix/Dovecot on Linode/Ubuntu 10.04 according to [this guide](http://library.linode.com/email/postfix/dovecot-mysql-ubuntu-10.04-lucid), admittedly I've never done this before. Local mail works just fine, but trying to send email to it from external addresses results in errors like this:

```
Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:

<address>@ni-mate.com

Technical details of permanent failure:
Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the recipient domain. We recommend contacting the other email provider for further information about the cause of this error. The error that the other server returned was: 553 553 Unknown recipient. (state 13).
```

I honestly have no idea what to do or which configuration files/logs anyone needs to see.

Comment: Is it a Linode server(I'm assuming) or EC2? If EC2, check the security group settings then confirm you setup your A records.

Comment: It is an Linode server.

Comment: Confirm that your MTA is listening and then try and access the appropriate port externally.

Comment: (Took me some time to figure this out/test it on other servers)
Postfix is listening for any ip4/6 address, when I do `telnet ni-mate.com smtp` it gives me `telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused` whereas servers not owned by me with working configuration give me:
`Trying <ip>...
Connected to <fqdn>.
Escape character is '^]'.`
and sometimes
`Connection closed by foreign host.` at the end.

I checked iptables and made a rule that explicitly accepts traffic on port 25, same results.

Comment: check /var/log/mail.log and /var/log/mail.err

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I didn't have working DNS records.

I wanted mail to arrive at mail.domain.com (Same server as domain.com), and be handled by that server. I made an A record for mail.domain.com that had the server's ip, so the same ip as domain.com. I then made mail.domain.com the MX record for domain.com so that mail sent to domain.com would go to mail.domain.com.